# how to tell graphical Emacs to shutdown cleanly from tty1?

Tags: emacsclient, linux, gui-emacs

## problem

Lately I run GNU Emacs mostly as GUI on X/tty7 (which I'll call "the desktop" as opposed to emacs-desktop) on one of my Debian laptops. Occasionally the desktop hangs, in which case I usually can goto tty1 and `sudo shutdown -[whatever] now`. Unfortunately this does not cause Emacs to shut down as cleanly as I'd like: I'd like Emacs to (e.g.) save any unsaved buffers and `desktop-save`, but that doesn't seem to get done.

So I'm thinking that, in this usecase, I should utter something from tty1 (before `shutdown`) to tell Emacs to shutdown cleanly ... but I don't know what to say. How to do this?

## solution

### thanks

TIA and for past help to the many fine folks @ [help-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs), esp [Yuri Khan](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2015-11/msg00219.html) for the initial suggestion and [Jorge A. Alfaro-Murillo](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2015-11/msg00223.html) for the more important details of this solution. Special thanks to [Faried Nawaz](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/8760/faried-nawaz) for [2 important advances](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18201/5444) that pretty-much solve the problem.

### server and client

One way that WFM (not entirely without problems--see `notes` below) is

1. **Preparation:**

1.1. Whenever you start Emacs, make it start a server instance. I did this by adding the following line to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
    (server-start)
```

1.2. Also in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, define a callable function to tell emacs to shutdown cleanly, with as few prompts as possible. [Faried Nawaz](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/8760/faried-nawaz) [recommended](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18171/how-to-tell-graphical-emacs-to-shutdown-cleanly-from-tty1#comment27339_18201)

```
    (defun my-kill-emacs ()
      "Set kill-emacs-query-functions , confirm-kill-emacs , and
    kill-emacs-hook to nil to quit emacs without any pesky prompts
    (except to save buffers)"
      (let (kill-emacs-query-functions confirm-kill-emacs kill-emacs-hook)
        (save-buffers-kill-emacs)))
```

1.3. Restart your emacs to be sure to incorporate your new `init.el` code.

2. **When you encounter tty7/desktop hang:** Goto tty1, and login if not already. Then do either of the following:

2.1. manually: from bash commandline, run

```
emacsclient -c -a '' -e '(my-kill-emacs)'
```

2.2. scripted: save the above line into an executable file à la `~/bin/shutdown_Emacs_cleanly.sh` and run it. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacsclient -c -a '' -e '(my-kill-emacs)'
```

### notes

1. If your (graphical) Emacs has no unsaved buffers when you kill it (as described above), Emacs will exit with no prompts. If your Emacs *has* unsaved buffers when you kill it, you will get prompts (from your character-mode Emacs in tty1) to save the buffers. (Writing a function that saves all unsaved buffers without *any* prompts is left as an exercise for the reader :-)
2. Whether or not you have unsaved buffers, when your tty1 commandline exits, its terminal handling may be "polluted": e.g. (and in roughly decreasing order of importance),

   - You will no longer see what you type at the bash prompt.
   - History browsing (via up/down-arrow key) also fails--at least, I cannot see anything on the commandline.
   - Hitting RET at the bash prompt no longer does a line feed, though it still produces a new prompt. This results in a display like

     `me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$ me@it:~$`

   My tty1 is always polluted by running the above; YMMV. Fortunately, as [Nawaz points out](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18201/5444), one can unpollute by calling `reset` from the tty1 commandline (after installing package=`ncurses-bin`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `(server-start)` it adds a function called `server-kill-emacs-query-function` (defined in `server.el`) to the `kill-emacs-query-functions` hook.  One solution that might work for you (I've tested it and it works for me) is to modify your emacsclient line to

```
emacsclient -c -a '' \
-e '(let (kill-emacs-query-functions confirm-kill-emacs kill-emacs-hook) (save-buffers-kill-emacs))'
```

Or better yet, define a function in your `.emacs` or `init.el` and call it from `emacsclient`:

```
(defun my-kill-emacs ()
  "Set kill-emacs-query-functions , confirm-kill-emacs , and
kill-emacs-hook to nil to quit emacs without any pesky prompts
(except to save buffers)"
  (let (kill-emacs-query-functions confirm-kill-emacs kill-emacs-hook)
    (save-buffers-kill-emacs)))
```

Your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacsclient -c -a '' -e '(my-kill-emacs)'
```

If running the above messes up your terminal, just type "reset" (part of Debian package=`ncurses-bin`).

Comment: The good news: `reset` WFM, thanks! The bad news ...

Comment: ... currently, running `(my-kill-emacs)` from my `init.el` seems to auto-answer the "wanna kill clients?" question, since I don't see that. But I still get and must interact reply to the "wanna exit?" question (followed by terminal pollution, solved by `reset`). Dunno if this is a version problems; FWIW I currently run `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5)`. Meanwhile, I'll try the commandlines.

Comment: I also still get and must reply to the "wanna exit?" question (followed by terminal pollution) with either of the commandlines `emacsclient -c -a '' -e '(my-kill-emacs)'` and `emacsclient -c -a '' -e '(let (kill-emacs-query-functions confirm-kill-emacs) (save-buffers-kill-emacs))'`. FWIW, I'm also running `lsb_release -ds`==`LMDE 2 Betsy`, `cat /etc/debian_version`==`8.2`, `uname -rv`==`3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04)`

Comment: Can you see if adding `kill-emacs-hook` to the list of `let` variables fixes the problem?

Comment: That works! Edited above (pending peer review) and I'll also edit my solution below.